# Fix multiple python installations

Tags: python, macos, unix

It looks like I have multiple python installations, which are making things difficult -- e.g. pip will tell me that a package has been installed through pip freeze, but when attempting to use it within a program, I get an error that it does not exist. Here are a few diagnostic tests I've run:

```
>>> import sys 
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-15.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.1.0-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gnureadline-6.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

As well as checking the path for python and some common tools:

```
which easy_install
/usr/local/bin/easy_install
which python
/usr/local/bin/python
which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

How can I fix it, short of doing a clean re-install of OS X?

Edited to add $PATH and .bashrc info:

My $PATH is as follows:

```
Users/me/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/me/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/urs/local/bin:/Users/me/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/urs/local/bin:/Users/me/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/bin:usr/local/python:usr/bin/python:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin: No such file or directory
```

-- the fact that it is returning an error makes me suspect that I've set up my .bash_profile wrong somehow. These are the only modifications I have made:

```
#Set architecture flags
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

#Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

#Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '/Users/me/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'

# The next line enables bash completion for gcloud.
source '/Users/me/workspace/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```

And this is my .bashrc:

```
# pip should only run if there is a virtualenv currently activated
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
# cache pip-installed packages to avoid re-downloading
export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip/cache
```

Comment: When you say "I get an error that it does not exist" are you sure you are using the correct name in the `import` statement? Packages aren't always imported with the names they are installed with.

Comment: if you want to keep the system's one only: `brew remove python`

Comment: @holdenweb, yes, I've double-checked. I'm importing packages the exact same way that I would on another machine where my dev environment is not broken, and that is not an issue.

Comment: @Maresh, already tried removing other installations with homebrew, but that does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: How your $PATH and $PYTHON_PATH defined? Check your .bash_profile or echo them

Comment: @Maresh, added the $PATH, bashrc and bash_profile info to the question. echoing my $PYTHON_PATH doesn't return anything.

Comment: It's `echo $PYTHONPATH`, no underscore.

Comment: Ok so it is really messed up indeed. `sys.executable` should show the same as `which python`. Did you make a manual install? Used macports? I'd remove the PIP virtualenv variable that's crap

Comment: also, how do you run you program? like `python myapp.py` or `./myapp.py` if it's the second please add the first lines of the file

Comment: To get the PATH variable, did you type `echo $PATH`? And that gets you the error message?

Comment: @maresh, I wasn't aware of PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV - it seems like a good idea to me

Comment: @jcoppens -- echoing $PYTHONPATH still returns nothing.

Comment: @Maresh -- thanks for the suggestion, I'll go ahead and remove the PIP virtualenv variable. So as far as I know, I just installed python via homebrew, and was using that version. With regards to running the program, I've run into the issue both within the python intepreter and when running a script as in python myapp.py. The most recent reproducible example that I have is attempting to run ipython notebook, and having it tell me that it cannot because it is missing a dependency. When I attempt to install the dependency via pip or easy_install, it does, but it still is missingwhen I run ipython

Comment: Currently the system python '/usr/local/bin' is the first in the path, if you want the brew version you need to change that (in my situation, the path to Anaconda is the first). Have a try at `brew doctor` it should flag this

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Manesh. So I think that my homebrew python is at `usr/local/Cellar/`? So should I put that before `/usr/local/bin` in my path? It looks like the most relevant alert that brew doctor gave me is: `Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.`, but I am not too sure what I should do to fix that.

Comment: Perhaps I want to `sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` as per this thread? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27146

Comment: whoops, sorry, meant to write @Maresh

Comment: Yea try that. It also make sense with the IPython problem, which seems to be under library and not Cellar

Comment: Mk, I removed the version of python in `Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. Does not seem to have fixed the issue, though -- when I pip install pyzmq, it tells me that there is already a version in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/......egg`. Running `ipython notebook` still tells me that it pyzmq doesn't exist, though.

Comment: On my Mac system, the _system_ python is `/usr/bin/python`, which is version 2.7.2. I also have a `brew`-installed python at `/usr/local/bin/python` (a symbolic link to `./Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/python`) which (because `/usr/local/bin` is earliest on my path) I tend to use as my own default Python 2 (none of the system stuff sees it because none of it uses `/usr/local/bin`). There's a `brew`-installed `/usr/local/bin/python3` (linked to `../Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/bin/python3`). They all co-exist quite happily.

But your system Python ISN'T in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: It sounds like you may only have IPython installed in one of your environments. If you use the command `python` instead of `ipython` does the issue still occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to fix it, so ended up doing a clean OS install and setting up a new python dev environment.